# Changing playlist shortcode thumbnail sizes?

Tags: shortcode, post-thumbnails, images, thumbnails, audio

I'm using `do_shortcode()` to display a custom WordPress audio playlist. By default the playlist will load cover art for each audio file (the attachment's featured image) and change according to what track is currently being played. The thing is, by default it loads the 150px x 150px thumbnail, but I would like to load a bigger size. There doesn't seem to be a simple option to change the size. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
do_shortcode( '[playlist ids="100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106"][/playlist]' );
```

I tried changing the thumbnail size in function.php by using `set_post_thumbnail_size()` and ran Regenerate Thumbnails, but nothing changed.

I also searched the WordPress core and found that the function that controls the playlist shortcode is called `wp_playlist_shortcode()`. There is a bit of code that sets the size of the thumbnail. I edited it just to see what happened, and it's the only thing that worked so far. Obviously, that is not the way to go, but that is where I'm currently stuck. Not sure if I should dump that here as well, I'd appreciate any pointers and help I can get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Demo Plugin - Fixed Size

Here's one suggestion as a demo plugin (PHP 5.4+):

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Custom Playlist Thumb Size */

namespace WPSE238646\PlaylistThumbSize;

add_shortcode( 'playlist', function( $atts = [], $content = '' )
{
    add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\src' , 10, 3 );
    $out = wp_playlist_shortcode( $atts, $content );
    remove_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\src' );    
    return $out;        
} );

function src( $image, $id, $size )
{
    add_filter( 'image_downsize', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\size', 10, 3 );
    return $image;
}

function size( $downsize, $id, $size )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    if( 'thumbnail' !== $size )
        return $downsize;   
    return image_downsize( $id, $size = 'large' );           // <-- Adjust size here!
}
```

Here we change the thumb size from `'thumbnail'` to `'large'`.

First we override the playlist shortcode callback, to better scope our filters and only target the playlist shortcodes.

Then we hook into the `image_downsize` filter to our needs, to call the `image_downsize()` function with the wanted thumb size. But we must remember to remove our filter callback right away to avoid an infinite recursive loop.

### Demo Plugin - Various Sizes

But it would be more flexible if we could write the thumb size as a shortcode attribute:

```
[playlist ids="12,34,56" _size="large"]
[playlist ids="12,34,56" _size="medium"]
```

Here we prefix our `_size` attribute with an underscore, just in case it gets supported by core in the future.

Here's a modification of our first demo plugin to support that (in a compact form):

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Playlist With _size Attribute */

namespace WPSE238646\PlaylistThumbSize;

add_shortcode( 'playlist', [ (new Playlist), 'shortcode' ] );

class Playlist
{
    protected $_size;

    public function shortcode( $atts = [], $content = '' )
    {
        $allowed_sizes = (array) get_intermediate_image_sizes(); // <-- Allowed sizes
        $this->_size = 'thumbnail';  // <-- Default size
        if( ! empty( $atts['_size' ] ) && in_array( $atts['_size' ], $allowed_sizes ) )
            $this->_size = $atts['_size' ]; 
        add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', [ $this, 'src' ] , 10, 3 );
        $out = wp_playlist_shortcode( $atts, $content );  // <-- Native playlist
        remove_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', [ $this, 'src' ] );
        return $out;       
    }     
    public function src( $image, $id, $size )
    {
        add_filter( 'image_downsize', [ $this, 'size' ], 10, 3 );
        return $image;
    }
    public function size( $downsize, $id, $size )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), [ $this, 'size' ] );
        if( 'thumbnail' !== $size )
            return $downsize;  
        return image_downsize( $id, $this->_size ); // <--Apply new size
    }
} // end class
```

Here we restrict the allowed sizes to `get_intermediate_image_sizes()`.

Hopefully you can test this further and adjust to your needs!

Comment: This is such an amazing answer!

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice to have this kind of attribute in the playlist shortcode or a playlist data filter @DaveRomsey